# NGINX config on WPEngine is not rewriting requests for assets (css/js)

Tags: wordpress, nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

We have a config we created with reference to https://nodeflame.com/how-to-serve-a-static-external-site-in-wordpress-subdirectory-on-wp-engine/. It is correctly rewriting the request for the document but is not rewriting requests for any of the assets.

We are trying to host a Vue JS site on a WPEngine url.

Our current config is as follows:

```
location ~* ^/activities/?(.*) {
proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
rewrite ^/activities/?$ / break;
rewrite ^/activities/(wp-(?:content|includes|admin))/(.*) /$1/$2 break;
rewrite ^/activity-finder/static/([^/]*)/(.*) /$1/$2 break;
rewrite ^/activities/([a-z-]+[.][a-z]+)$ /$1 break;
rewrite ^/activities/([^/]*)/?$ /$1/ break;
rewrite ^/activities/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /$1/$2/ break;
rewrite ^/activities/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /$1/$2/$3/ break;
rewrite ^/activities/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /$1/$2/$3/$4/ break;
rewrite ^/activities/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/ break;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Cache-Control $http_cache_control;
proxy_pass https://xxxxx.azurewebsites.net;
}
```

Can anyone offer any help?